# How to represent bunch of files as one file on Windows for direct reading

Tags: windows, file-io, named-pipes

I'd like to make one file representing (linking) bunch of files - something as on Linux named pipe do. The motivation is not to concatenate files (not to create the new one when I have originals and I want to keep them) so do not duplicate data. For example I want to use this to load videos from camera which are divided by approx. 2 GB.

Comment: Would something like a directory containing junctions (symlinks) do?

Comment: *Some* Windows command-line applications will accept a named pipe as input, so that may be an option.  And well-designed applications will have the functionality you're asking about built in, assuming that it is appropriate to the technology.  Otherwise, the only solution would be a file system filter driver, and it seems unlikely to be worth the effort involved.  (You might want to go looking to see if you can find an existing third-party solution.)